# Any difference b/w running exe manually and task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have a console job for generting pdfs(to generate 10000 pdfs)

1. When executing through task scheduler I am facing error "window handle exception" after generating 1100 pdfs
2. When executing manually or from command prompt, job running successfully and generating 10000 pdfs.

Can any one suggest what may be the issue while running through task scheduler.

Suggest me any software to find any memory leaks, GC Collect, Windows Handles utilized.

Comment: Does the task scheduler launch 10000 generation jobs, or are all the jobs contained in the one console job?

Comment: If you don't have any logging to help you, you can use Windows' Event Viewer to check if there's a crash reported, in the Application section.

Comment: It is one console job, creating 10000 pdfs in for loop

Comment: I am logging exception into text file, it is displaying error as "ERROR CREATING WINDOW HANDLE".   When running through task scheduler, Job running successfully in my computer. but not working when running in Server

Answer (score 0):

What about attaching to the actual process when the task scheduler launches the app? In Visual Studio, Debug > Attach to Process. If the exception is happening right away, you can add a delay to your program so you have time to attach.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000); //Sleep for two minutes
```

That way when the exception is hit, your IDE will break on the line and might give you more detail in the inner exception.

If you app runs on a remote server you can install the remote debugging tools and still attach to the process.